# How to assign EventHandler to dynamic object in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, events, eventhandler

I'm trying to create an Interface for my project and i created a struct of PSU like:

```
public struct PSU
{
    public CheckBox CallHostessButton0, CallHostessButton1,
        ReadLightButton0, ReadLightButton1, ReadLightButton2, ReadLightButton3;
    public PictureBox BeltLight, SmokeLight;
}

public bool AssignObjectsToPSU(PSU psu, CheckBox CallHostessBtn0, CheckBox CallHostessBtn1,
CheckBox ReadLightBtn0, CheckBox ReadLightBtn1, CheckBox ReadLightBtn2, CheckBox ReadLightBtn3,
PictureBox BeltLght, PictureBox SmokeLght)
{
    try
    {
        Log("[Info] Assigning objects to PUS units...");
        psu.CallHostessButton0 = CallHostessBtn0;  
        // -> In here if possible <-
        psu.CallHostessButton1 = CallHostessBtn1;
        psu.ReadLightButton0 = ReadLightBtn0;
        psu.ReadLightButton1 = ReadLightBtn1;
        psu.ReadLightButton2 = ReadLightBtn2;
        psu.ReadLightButton3 = ReadLightBtn3;
        psu.BeltLight = BeltLght; psu.SmokeLight = SmokeLght;

        LogReport("[OK]");
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        LogReport("[Failed]");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And i need to assign object events for these objects like:

```
PSU TestPSU = new PSU;
TestPSU.CallHostessButton0 = checkBox1;
TestPSU.CallHostessButton0.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged);
```

---

So I need 12 of these "PSUs" and I have to assign them for each. Like above. Here is my question: Is there any easy way to do this assignments? Ex: In a method or loop? Something like:

```
public void AssignEvents(PSU p, CheckBox cb)
{
    p.CallHostessButton0.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckedChanged);
}
```

Or inside the struct definition:

```
psu.CallHostessButton0 = CallHostessBtn0;
psu.CallHostessButton0.CheckedChanged = += new EventHandler(CallHostessBtn0_CheckedChanged);
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a delegate to `AssignObjectsToPSU` as an additional parameter

```
public bool AssignObjectsToPSU(PSU psu, ..., EventHandler checkedChangedHandler)
{
    ...
    psu.CheckedChanged  += checkedChangedHandler;
    ...
}
```

Then you can call it with

```
if (AssignObjectsToPSU(psu, ..., checkBox1_CheckedChanged)) {
    ...
}
```

Just make sure not to append braces `()` after `checkBox1_CheckedChanged`.

And in a loop

```
foreach (PSU psu in myPsuList) {
    if (!AssignObjectsToPSU(psu, ..., checkBox1_CheckedChanged)) {
        break;
    }
}
```